# Looking for recommendations on reporting front end to work with SSAS/SSRS

Tags: javascript, .net, reporting-services, ssas, business-intelligence

I'm working on designing/building a BI solution, so far we have a very simplistic setup using the Microsoft BI Stack.

We are looking at adding reports built into our webpage for clients to use, which means they need to be relatively simple to use (pivot table style would be out of the question) I am envisioning a selection of canned reports with certain parameters being set by the client (ie. date range, document type)

Can anyone suggest any products that interface with SSAS/SSRS either .NET or Javascript that could achieve this type of interactive report?

FYI we are using SQL 2008 though I am considering prototyping with 2012 for Power view at the least.

Sorry if I have been vague, I'm still ironing this out.

Edit:
To clarify a bit more after Jamie's comment, What I am looking for that (as far as I know) SSRS can't meet is the ability to seamlessly embed the reports into a client facing 'portal website' and for the controls to be very user friendly; the client base for this is far from being computer/tech savvy.

I have looked at both D3.js and Highcharts but from what I've found they aren't meant to hookup to something like ssas.

Comment: What you are asking is too vague. In fact, it sounds like you are describing SSRS itself: "canned reports with certain parameters being set by the client"

Comment: Ok that is a good point, I guess I will edit and try to clarify a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with your edits, it still sounds like you are describing SSRS itself, particularly the Report Manager website. While not very flexible, I think it's simple enough for anyone that can handle a web browser. It will

If you need more flexibilty,  you can embed SSRS reports in another website easily, whether .net or not. (Use URL access and an iframe to integrate with pretty much anything.) You can collect the parameters with any method you'd like, or use the built in parameters interface.

Granted, report authoring in SSRS requires someone who is technically literate, but it sounds like the end users don't need to author the reports, they just need the ability to run them on demand.

Comment: Thank you Jamie, I was not aware that SSRS reports were embeddable in that manner I will definitely investigate this once I get the back end of my prototype strung together. Thank you for the information.